# wdio-junit-reporter marking retried tests as failed

Tags: junit, mocha.js, wdio-v6

We have tests done with mocha and wdio using junit-reporter to generate reports in the pipeline(s). Recently test jobs started failing and it seems it's due to retried tests being marked as failed.

Tests are retried up to three times and we noticed that before if test fails in first run but passes in the next (retry) one, first run was marked as skipped in the report. Example below:
[chrome 90.0.4430.212 windows #0-0]    ? should test something
[chrome 90.0.4430.212 windows #0-0]    ✓ should test something

Now if test fails in the first run and passes in the next one, first run is marked as failed in the report which fails the test job. Example below:
[chrome 91.0.4472.114 windows #0-0]    ✖ should test something
[chrome 91.0.4472.114 windows #0-0]    ✓ should test something

Was there some change in wdio runner or junit-reporter recently that could cause this behavior? Is there a way to revert to old one where test(s) are marked as skipped?

Comment: did you update you npm dependencies to get a different result? If yes, what changed?

Comment: I updated all WebdriverIO packages from 6.5.x to 7.7.x and this issue started appearing. I went back to 6.5.x and everything works fine again. Issue is created in wdio repo as well (https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/7104).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved, check [issues-7104](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/7104) for details.